# Is it secure to save passwords on server as the modulus?

Tags: security

I am afraid that someone can crack and extract the users passwords and they might be using it on other sites.

I thought I would save passwords as 1s and 0s. A would be 65%2=1 B would be 0 and C would be 1 and so on. so the passwords ABC and CBA are equivalent.

But it is not easy to reverse it (unlike md5) which can be found by searching on the internet.

So, that is equivalent to limiting the users to a specific range of passwords.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In general, making up your own hashing algorithms is a really bad idea.  The scheme you've proposed has a *very* small search space, so would be easy to brute-force.

The kind of attack you refer to with MD5 is called a rainbow table attack.  You can mostly avoid this by "salting" your passwords:

- When you set a user's password, prefix it with a random string (the salt) of say 8 characters or more.
- When you hash the password (with MD5 or SHA2 or whatever), store both the salt and the hash.
- To verify the password, look up the user's salt, and prepend it to the password they entered.  Hash that, and compare it with the hash you have stored.

Better yet, use bcrypt, where most libraries will already handle salting for you (and will embed the salt in the generated hash).